# Python pandas time series resample function extends time index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm playing around with some financial time series data in pandas, and I'm trying to take a resample of some timestamp data. This is the starting data:

```
start_data

Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 749880 entries, 2012-07-06 03:00:00 to 2013-09-11 23:59:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
TickMean    749880  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)

start_data.TickMean
Out[18]: 
2012-07-06 03:00:00    1.541194
2012-07-06 03:01:00    1.541216
2012-07-06 03:02:00    1.541201
2012-07-06 03:03:00    1.541088
2012-07-06 03:04:00    1.540999
2012-07-06 03:05:00    1.541011
2012-07-06 03:06:00    1.541090
2012-07-06 03:07:00    1.541256
2012-07-06 03:08:00    1.541341
2012-07-06 03:09:00    1.541386
2012-07-06 03:10:00    1.541511
2012-07-06 03:11:00    1.541469
2012-07-06 03:12:00    1.541506
2012-07-06 03:13:00    1.541584
2012-07-06 03:14:00    1.541453
...
2013-09-11 23:45:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:46:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:47:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:48:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:49:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:50:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:51:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:52:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:53:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:54:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:55:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:56:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:57:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:58:00    1.602015
2013-09-11 23:59:00    1.602015
Name: TickMean, Length: 749880, dtype: float64
```

And when I try a 40-minute resample, the time range is expanded:

```
start_data = start_data.resample('40min')

start_data
Out[14]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 25344 entries, 2012-01-07 00:00:00 to 2013-12-10 23:20:00
Freq: 40T
Data columns (total 1 columns):
TickMean    18749  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)

start_data.TickMean

Out[15]: 
2012-01-07 00:00:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 00:40:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 01:20:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 02:00:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 02:40:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 03:20:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 04:00:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 04:40:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 05:20:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 06:00:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 06:40:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 07:20:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 08:00:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 08:40:00    1.5706
2012-01-07 09:20:00    1.5706
...
2013-12-10 14:00:00    1.594563
2013-12-10 14:40:00    1.594796
2013-12-10 15:20:00    1.594766
2013-12-10 16:00:00    1.593523
2013-12-10 16:40:00    1.593171
2013-12-10 17:20:00    1.593702
2013-12-10 18:00:00    1.595145
2013-12-10 18:40:00    1.595796
2013-12-10 19:20:00    1.595527
2013-12-10 20:00:00    1.595099
2013-12-10 20:40:00    1.595060
2013-12-10 21:20:00    1.595575
2013-12-10 22:00:00    1.595575
2013-12-10 22:40:00    1.595575
2013-12-10 23:20:00    1.595575
Freq: 40T, Name: TickMean, Length: 25344, dtype: float64
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Why is it doing this?

Quick edit: I know the 40-minute frequency is weird, but other frequencies have the same effect.

Edit 2: Yep, it was something silly. I thought the index would be sorted.

```
start_data

Out[23]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 749880 entries, 2012-07-06 03:00:00 to 2013-09-11 23:59:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
TickMean    749880  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)

start_data.index.min()
Out[24]: Timestamp('2012-01-07 00:00:00', tz=None)

start_data.index.max()
Out[25]: Timestamp('2013-12-10 23:59:00', tz=None)
```

Edit 3: As a bonus for anyone that is encountering weird problems like this, my date data was DAY FIRST instead of month first. So that threw everything off as well. This was addressed using the dayfirst=True option.

```
ask_data.index = pd.to_datetime(ask_data.index, dayfirst=True)

ask_data
Out[34]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 749880 entries, 2012-06-07 03:00:00 to 2013-11-09 23:59:00
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Open      749880  non-null values
High      749880  non-null values
Low       749880  non-null values
Close     749880  non-null values
Volume    749880  non-null values
dtypes: float64(5)

ask_data.index.min()
Out[35]: Timestamp('2012-06-07 03:00:00', tz=None)

ask_data.index.max()
Out[36]: Timestamp('2013-11-09 23:59:00', tz=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your index is in order? you can check this by:

```
print start_data.index.min(), start_data.index.max(), start_data.index.is_monotonic
```